# Numeric keyboard appears for the Input type password in Cordova Projects

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, phonegap-plugins

In my PhoneGap project, the login screen has two fields mobile no and password.
The Mobile No. is numeric type and password is alphanumeric. When user tap on the Mobile Number, the numeric keyboard is appeared but when user switch to password field, the numeric keyboard is not converted to the text keyboard. My code is as:

```
<div id="mobile_number_div" class="options textDiv">
    <input type="tel" id="loginMobile" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile as 10 digits (eg 0871234567)" class="textBox"/>
</div>
<div id="password_div" class="options textDiv">
    <input type="password" id="loginPasswrd" placeholder="Password" class="textBox"/>
</div>
```

I face above problem in two android devices HTC 10 and HTC Desire 825 with Android 6.0.1 and all the other devices are working fine. The HTC 10 and Desire 825 are used as "TouchPal" as Keyboard.
The Same code is working fine on iOS also.

While running on the HTC 10 device, I get this log many times:

> W/InputMethodSettingValuesWrapper(13556): ascii capable subtype
>   enabled imi not found. Fall back to English Keyboard subtype.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<input type="password" id="loginPasswrd" placeholder="Password" class="textBox" pattern="\-?\d+(\.\d{0,})?">
```

Adding that pattern should bring up the correct keyboard.

Comment: Hi H2ONOCK, thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion  but it does not work in the HTC 10 and desire 825